# Django contact form which sends email

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, email, heroku

I have a question regarding creating contact form.

From what I understand when someone sends it I automatically receive an email that I put in the settings. Can a reversed thing be done? I mean when someone fills the form all the information go from one email account to another. For example: user fills the title and message in the form, sends it and then that message goes from one set e-mail address (for example gmail) and then to another e-mail address (for example Outlook).

I want to do that because my client doesn't want to give me the password to his e-mail. So I have to create my own e-mail on gmail and use it to send to client's e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can negotiate adjusting client's mailbox settings you could:

1. Prefix/suffix subjects of emails sent via the form, e.g.

```
 form = ContactForm(request.POST)
 if form.is_valid():
        subject = "[WebForm]: " + form.cleaned_data['subject']
```

2. Selectively forward prefixed messages to desired e-mail address. See [this video](https://youtu.be/bkDIAhWkJZE?t=121) for how it's done in Gmail.